# Increasing image quality on an image that is 262*64 px in Inkscape

Tags: wordpress, inkscape

I have a website that uses WordPress and alidropship, I’ve just created a logo for the site using Inkscape but when I upload it at the recommended size of 262*64 px the image appears very blurry on the site. How do I increase the image quality in Inkscape so that it will remain clean and clear at that size?

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply the width/height and the image will be scaled accordingly. 
262x64 * 2 = 524x128
262x64 * 3 = 768x192
etc.

It's possible that you're not really experiencing problems with the image/logo itself however, and rather just the setup of your WordPress theme. Some themes are way too aggressive in handling images, and compresses way too hard. It might also just be a CSS scaling issue, again by the theme.

Possibly, if you're running an image compression plugin, disable it and try again with your previous logo file.